# How do I prevent the "Untrusted server" dialogue pop-up in Git GUI?

Tags: git, github, git-gui

Due to the nature of my network configuration, this popup is inevitable. This is expected, but it pops up very frequently and requires clicking past it EVERY TIME. Is there any way I can simply prevent this popup from occurring completely?

[image: untrusted server git gui screenshot]

The window occurs almost every time you change tabs or select a different menu within the git GUI. Clicking "Cancel" closes the window.

Comment: Do you connect to the rest of the Internet through a proxy?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Are you using a non-default antivirus or firewall, a TLS MITM device, monitoring software, or any other sort of proxy?  If so, does completely uninstalling that software and rebooting fix the problem?

Comment: I use a proxy to another server for certain network file transfers but I don't have internet access.

Comment: I use windows 10 on a VM, on this system. It is likely git GUI is just not going to like my network setup, I'm willing to go to extreme lengths to make this popup disappear, like even a macro to auto click cancel or something